# PHP - $foo = !!'foo'; echo $foo; - Why does it print '1'?

Tags: php

Someone could explain me how these two exclamation points works?

```
<?php
      $foo = !!'foo'; 
      echo $foo;
?>
```

Comment: it prints `1`, because `'foo'` is true, and Not, Not foo is still true.  In the same way that `$foo = !'foo';` prints noting which is typical of falsy values.

Comment: further if you type cast `'foo'` to a boolean (which is basically what you are doing), `echo (bool)'foo';` it prints `1`  So this is basically `echo !!(bool)'foo';`

Comment: Fun note: `echo true;` outputs `'1'` and `echo false;` outputs `''`. [`var_dump()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) is the best choice for debug output.